Nextjs Failed to find Server Action "null"
Hitting this log only on production and is not reproducible everytime:
Error: Failed to find Server Action "null". This request might be from an older or newer deployment. Original error: Invariant: Missing 'next-action' header.
    at ry (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:1666)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:7035
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
    at rm (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:6350)
    at rq (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:1255)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:3935
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)
    at Object.wrap (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:13:16239)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:3825
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:338:14)

Env:
"next": "14.1.4",
has anyone manage to resolve it?

This solves the problem? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/59105#discussioncomment-8223381

@Kobra Unfortanatelly no, i have added it like this:
// https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/59105
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            value: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_BASE_URL,
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

but the issue persist :(
